# Анимация вычеркивания после клика

Tags: css, анимация

Хочу добавить анимацию плавного вычеркивания для элемента `li` после клика по нему, но не могу понять где нужно устанавливать `transition` чтобы это сделать, т.к не в дочерним, ни в родительском элементе это не работает. Как можно это сделать?

```
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li class="task" 
        id="breakfest" 
        onclick="deleteItem('breakfest')">
      Позавтракать</li> 
    <li class="task" 
        id="teeth"
        onclick="deleteItem('teeth')">
      Почистить зубы</li>
    <li class="task" 
        id="call"
        onclick="deleteItem('call')">
      Перезвонить Геннадию</li> 
  </ul>

function deleteItem(item) {
  document.getElementById(`${item}`).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}

.task {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zutetayasa/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-decoration`, который выполняет роль перечёркивания текста, вроде как, с анимацией не дружит.

По этому есть вот такой вариант, для "вычёркивания" текста использовать псевдо-элемент.

```js
function deleteItem(item) {
  document.getElementById(`${item}`).className = 'task del';
}
```

```css
.task {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.task::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #07f;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(65% - 2px);
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear .2s;
}

.task.del::after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="todo-list">
  <li class="task" id="breakfest" onclick="deleteItem('breakfest')">
    Позавтракать</li><br>
  <li class="task" id="teeth" onclick="deleteItem('teeth')">
    Почистить зубы</li><br>
  <li class="task" id="call" onclick="deleteItem('call')">
    Перезвонить Геннадию</li>
</ul>
```